# Wordpress WP Ulike plugin, can't add another user table (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a website using Wordpress where people can like and leave comments to articles. I am using a plugin called WP ULike, and I want to add another table to the database that the plugin creates when I launch it in my website.

The PHP code used to create all the tables is as follows:

```
/**
 * Fired for each blog when the plugin is activated.
 *
 * @since    3.1
 */
private static function single_activate() {

    global $wpdb;

    if ( get_site_option( 'wp_ulike_dbVersion' ) != WP_ULIKE_DB_VERSION ) {

        $posts_table = $wpdb->prefix . "ulike";
        if ( $wpdb->get_var( "show tables like '$posts_table'" ) != $posts_table ) {
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $posts_table . " (
                    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                    `post_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                    `date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
                    `ip` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
                    `user_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
                    `status` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
                    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
                );";

            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
            dbDelta( $sql );
        } else {
            // Fix an old issue with user_id column
            $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE $posts_table CHANGE `user_id` `user_id` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL" );
        }
    }
}
```

and when I activate the plugin, I can see all of the tables appearing fine. So I decided to add another table, called competencies table, to the database. my code for that is as follows:

```
$comptencies_table = $wpdb->prefix . "ulike_competencies";
if ( $wpdb->get_var( "show tables like '$competencies_table'" ) != $competencies_table ) {
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $comptencies_table . " (
    `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `competency_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `date_time_acquired` datetime NOT NULL,
    `ip` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `user_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `competency_value` smallint(5) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );";

    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
    dbDelta( $sql );
} else {
    // Fix an old issue with user_id column
    $wpdb->query( "ALTER TABLE $competencies_table CHANGE `user_id` `user_id` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL" );
}
```

so pretty much the same code for the previous table but with some different variables, and it is located on the same file just below the code for the other table.

But when I deactivate and reactivate the plugin, and then go and check the database, the new table is nowhere to be seen.

Does anyone know why this could be?

Thanks!

Comment: where are you putting your code?

Comment: it's literally just below the code for the first table which works, in that  private static function single_activate().

Comment: I don't have the plugin, but are you sure you want to do that? When the plugin owner updates the plugin it may overwrite your code. The problem might relate to the typo as in `$comptencies_table` is different to `$competencies_table`

Comment: hey there, I fixed the typo and the problem is still there. the plugin hasn't been updated in a while, so I was kinda banking on that.  it doesn't work anyway for some reason...

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, do you mean the plugin generally or just your code?

Comment: What I mean is, that the table I want to add doesn’t get added to the database. So the posts table -which came as a default with the plugin - will be there when I go and check, but the competencies table is not there.

Comment: the plugin works perfectly fine, it's just the edit I made doesn't show up at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the 'WP_ULIKE_DB_VERSION' value on main file. (Also you can add this table manually in the database)